# Why can't I open 'HKLM\\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum' from my Delphi 2010 program?

Tags: delphi, registry

I am trying to write a utility to automate the process of setting up a PC to test devices using the FTDI serial>USB converter. This requires finding installed device information and writing to the above hive. I have implemented elevation of privileges and signed the program but it will not allow me to open the key. I can open the parent but not the "Enum" key or it's children.

```
procedure TForm4.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  aReg: TRegistry;
  sl: TStringList;
begin
  aReg := TRegistry.Create;
  try
    aReg.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
    if aReg.OpenKey('\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum', false) then // \Enum\USB\VID_0403&PID_6001', false) then
    begin
      sl := TStringList.Create;
      try
        aReg.GetKeyNames(sl);
        Memo1.Lines.Assign(sl);
        Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(sl.Count) + ' keys found.');
      finally
        sl.Free;
      end;
    end else
      Memo1.Lines.Add('Could not open key');
  finally
    aReg.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Only "system" has full control access by default. Not so for "administrators". You can view permissions on a key by using the regedit program. You can read the reason [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff546173(v=vs.85).aspx). You can use 'OpenKeyReadOnly' to read the information, but you would better use the api mentioned in the link.

Comment: You should test for Errors and supply them, best guess, use: TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ);

Comment: @FredS: It would be better to use `OpenKeyReadOnly()` instead of `OpenKey()`.

Comment: Opening the key in read only mode does not satisfy the " and writing to" requirement.

Answer (score 7):

"Administrators" do not have full access to the `Enum` key by default. Thus, elevation of privileges will not help when you want to open the key with `KEY_ALL_ACCESS` access rights.

`TRegisty` uses `KEY_ALL_ACCESS` by default on its operations, unless you specify a different access in its constructor or `Access` property.

When you are opening the key to read it contents, you can either:

- use the overloaded constructor and specify `KEY_READ` as your desired access.
- use the `Access` property to set the desired access to `KEY_READ` before opening the key.
- use `OpenKeyReadOnly()` instead of `OpenKey()`.

But beware this note on MSDN:

[HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum Registry Tree](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff546173.aspx)

> The **Enum** tree is reserved for use by operating system components, and its layout is subject to change. Drivers and user-mode [Device Installation Components](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff541277.aspx) must use system-supplied functions, such as [IoGetDeviceProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549203.aspx) and [SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551967.aspx), to extract information from this tree. *Drivers and Windows applications must not access the **Enum** tree directly*. You can view the **Enum** tree directly by using Registry Editor when you debug drivers.

You should consider using the alternative API mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: Ahh, this looks promising. Thanks for your help.